# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'Context.getSharedPreferences()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

I try to access my sharedpreference from a fragment in my app like this:

```
SharedPreferences sp_app_prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(getActivity().getPackageName(), MODE_PRIVATE);

String path = sp_app_prefs.getString("path", "");
```

but I am getting a NullPointerException:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
```

I really don't understand why, it doesn't make sense to me.
Calling this sharedpreference from an activity works totaly fine.
What am I missing?

Here is the full string method:

```
public String getFilePath(int i) {

        File filePath;


        SharedPreferences sp_app_prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(getActivity().getPackageName(), MODE_PRIVATE);
        String path = sp_app_prefs.getString("path", "");

        filePath = new File(path);


    }


    return String.valueOf(filePath);
}
```

Hope someone can help me

Comment: The code looks good to me. It looks like the activity that launched the fragment is giving a null context. Can you please share how you are launching this fragment from the activity?

Comment: Use PrefereneceManager- https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceManager#getDefaultSharedPreferences(android.content.Context)

Comment: Where in your Fragment's lifecycle do you call `getFilePath()`?

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is ambiguous.
but i guess you are putting code in onCreateView() method body.
instead you should put your code in onViewCreated() method body.

use following code in onViewCreated() method...

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("filename", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=  sharedPreferences.edit();

        editor.putString("key", "value");
        editor.apply();

        String text = sharedPreferences.getString("key", null);

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: I am calling it from a String method inside my fragment. See edited question